# Magento2 - Show Ex. GST on everywhere

Tags: magento2, price

I want to show Ex. GST on everywhere of the store with each price for example if a product price is **$15.00** I want to display it like **"$15.00 EX. GST"** in the cart, product page all over the store.

Please suggest me the solution.

Thanks